# filtering elements between 2 dates

Tags: plugin-development

I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this, but I can't work it out...

I'm trying to add date filters to the formerly submission export, but I can't work out how to filter out the submissions between 2 dates. I got it working with a bit of a hack:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Formerly_Submission');
$fromDate   = craft()->request->getPost('fromDate');
$fromDate = DateTime::createFromString($fromDate,   craft()->timezone) ;
$toDate   = craft()->request->getPost('toDate');
$toDate = DateTime::createFromString($toDate,   craft()->timezone) ;

//A bit of a hack, in my case these date fields are always the same anyway
$criteria->dateCreated = '>= ' . $fromDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME);
$criteria->dateUpdated = '<= ' . $toDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME);
```

I tried all sorts of ways to do it properly, things like

```
$criteria->dateCreated ='and, > ' . $fromDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME) . ', > ' . $toDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME)'
```

anyone know how to do it properly?

Answer (score 4):

You call it a bit of a hack, but I think the way you're doing it is the proper way:

```
$criteria->dateCreated = '>= ' . $fromDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME);
$criteria->dateUpdated = '<= ' . $toDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME);
```

Your last example would work (with a syntax change) if you were you looking for a date range within a single field (either dateCreated or dateUpdated) like so, but not across two fields:

```
$criteria->dateUpdated = array('and', '>='.$fromDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME), '<='.$toDate->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME));
```

Comment: thanks brad, I knew I was close, thinking back I was probably doing something silly like having a < wrong way round